# React Js : How to use UseState In CallBack?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have below code :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

function ReactForm() {
    const iState =[{
        Name : '',
        Email :'',
        Salary :0
    
    }]
const [state, setstate] = useState(iState);
    function validationHandler()
    {
        console.log(state);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            Name : <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setstate(...state, state.Name=e.target.value)}}></input>
            <br></br>            
            Email : <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setstate(...state, state.Email=e.target.value)}}></input>
            <br></br>            
            Salary : <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>{setstate(...state, state.Salary=e.target.value)}}></input>
            <br></br>
            <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ReactForm
```

I am performing basic validations here. I am receiving error : `TypeError: state is not iterable`

After going through few links on stackoverflow , I added - [ ] over state , but it did not helped.

**EDIT 1 :**

After Adding :- `setstate({...state, state.Name: e.target.value})`  : Unexpected token, expected "," (18:79)

[image]

Comment: `setstate({...state, state.Name: e.target.value})`

Comment: @boxdox - I applied this, but getting error , please see Edit1

Comment: Also move the `iState ` outside of your ReactForm function else you are creating a new `iState` each time for every keystroke .

Comment: you can keep the iState as object and update state like this: setstate({...state, Salary: e.target.value});

Comment: iState is created every render but only the first one will be used. Also your state is an array but you seem to think it's an object. The `=` in the setter instead of `:` too seems like you need to learn some JS fundamentals better first

Comment: @CSharper you need to pass the previous state to do that.
`setstate(prevState => ({...prevState , prevState.Name: e.target.value}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the setState called for each of the inputs you can make use of the `name` attribute and can refactor the code as below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function ReactForm() {
  const [state, setstate] = useState({
    Name: '',
    Email: '',
    Salary: 0,
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    setstate((prevState) => ({...prevState, [name]: value}));
  };

  function validationHandler() {
    console.log(state);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Name :{' '}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.Name}
        name="Name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br></br>
      Email :{' '}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.Email}
        name="Email"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br></br>
      Salary :{' '}
      <input
        type="text"
        value={state.Salary}
        name="Salary"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <br></br>
      <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ReactForm;
```

Refer:

[Controlled Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Answer (score 2):

Your initial state is an array of objects. I'm not sure whether this is what you are looking for.

Assume your `iState` is (Just an object)

```
const iState = {
  Name: '',
  Email: '',
  Salary: 0
}
```

Then you should do something like this in your `onChange` listener

```
// setState should use camel case for best pratice BTW
const handleChangeName = e => setstate({
  ...state, 
  Name: e.target.value
});
```

If you are sticking to the array state, the listener should look something like this instead.

```
const handleChangeName = e => setstate([
  ...state,
  {
    ...state[0], // or whatever index you may use in the future
    Name: e.target.value
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can do the following assignment** `state.Name=e.target.value` ****:

You are using an `array` not an object, so there is nothing you can access using `state.Name=e.target.value`

So if wanna access it directly the same way you used you have to use `state` property as OBJECT not as ARRAY:

```js
const iState = {
  Name: '',
  Email: '',
  Salary: 0

}
```

And the standard for the component that has `form` to handle is to use **stateful** component

**OR**

You can use stateless (functional) component and make form each form field its own state:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [salary, setSalary] = useState(0);
```

So the component will be:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'

function ReactForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [salary, setSalary] = useState(0)

  function validationHandler() {
    console.log('Name: ' + name);
    console.log('Email: ' + email);
    console.log('Salary: ' + salary);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      Name : <input
        type="text"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}></input>

      <br></br>

      Email : <input
        type="text"
        value={email}
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}></input>

      <br></br>

      Salary : <input
        type="text"
        value={salary}
        onChange={(e) => setSalary(e.target.value)}></input>

      <br></br>

      <button onClick={validationHandler}>Validate Us</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ReactForm;
```